# Part of a Media Query not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm currently working on trying to make a shop responsive and I'm having the following issue.

I'm using media queries to style the shop and a particular range within the media query won't the **AT ALL.**

It works perfectly in the rest of the media queries however, in this particular one it doesn't make any changes.

Here's an example of one of my **WORKING** media queries:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 685px) and (min-width: 640px)
{
    #ShopMiddleHolderEShop {float:left; width:915px;}
    #rightSideHolder {padding-left:15px; width:37%; float:left; padding-bottom:8px;margin-right:50px;}
    .prodTable {float:left; width:105%}
    #prodListView {float:left; width:240px;}
    .prodTable td {width:130%; float:left;}
    .prodTmbHld {width:80%; margin:8px 0 0 0;/* display: list-item; *//* float: left; */}
    fieldset.prodTmb {/* float:left; */ margin:0 auto;padding:5px 0;width:99.5%; height:150px;}
    .prodTmbImg { width:145px; height:143px; float:right;}
    .prodTmbImg img { width:140px; height:140px; float:left}
    .prodDsc { padding-left:10px; float:left; width:145px; font-size:12px; line-height:14px}
}
```

And here is the range that **DOESN'T work**!

```css
@media all and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 590px)
{
    #ShopMiddleHolderEShop {float:left; width:915px;}
    #rightSideHolder {padding-left:15px; width:37%; float:left; padding-bottom:8px;margin-right:50px;}
    .prodTable {float:left; width:105%}
    #prodListView {float:left; width:auto; margin-right:320px;}
    .prodTable td {width:130%; float:left;}
    .prodTmbHld {width:70%; margin:8px 0 0 0;/* display: list-item; *//* float: left; */}
    fieldset.prodTmb {/* float:left; */ margin:0 auto;padding:5px 0;width:99.5%; height:150px;}
    .prodTmbImg { width:145px; height:143px; float:right;}
    .prodTmbImg img { width:140px; height:140px; float:left}
    .prodDsc { padding-left:10px; float:left; width:145px; font-size:12px; line-height:14px}
    #viewNav { float:left; width: 170px; border-right:1px solid #8FBCD1}
    #viewNav span { float:left; padding-left:8px}
    #viewNav a {float:left; border-right:1px solid #8FBCD1; padding:0 8px}
    #ShopUnderHeaderHolder { float:left; width:10%; background:#a8a8a8}                         
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that you have conflicting or overlapping media queries. The **order** matters! Also for those widths, why is your first property 915px?

Comment: Missing `;` after `padding:0 8px` of `#viewNav a`

Comment: @James doesn't matter, it's at the end

Comment: I don't think missing closing tags matter in css classes at the end as Webeno stated but I'll close them all just to make sure!

Comment: @T.J.Wallace totally unnecessary, won't change anything

Comment: Turns out it was over lapping queries @webeno you'll be glad to know!

Accidentally pasted in an extra media query starting with max-width 640px and it wasn't closing so it was effect anything below 640!

Comment: well, it was originally suggested by @Paulie_D, but I'm glad you solved it... you may want to add it as an answer to your own question, it might help someone...

Comment: Sorry I thought it was you that posted that ! Apologies.

But thanks for all the help regardless!

And thank you @Paulie_D for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had overlapping CSS.

I had accidentally copy and pasted the same media query above the one I was working on but it hadn't been closed.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width:640px) and (min-width:590px)
{

/*Some code here*/
```

I removed this code and it worked perfectly!